# Does MBProgressHUD showWhilePerformingSelector: Execute Selected Method on Another Thread?

Tags: iphone, multithreading, mbprogresshud

I'm utilizing `MBProgressHUD` in my project. I'm using the method `showWhilePerformingSelector:` which is calling a method which utilizes `NSURLConnection`. I read in another Stack Overflow question that people were having trouble using `NSURLConnection` in a secondary thread because the thread would be killed before the delegate methods could be fired.

In essence, the question is, does `MBProgressHUD`'s `showWhilePerformingSelector:` method run the selected method on a different thread? If so, how would I go about utilizing that main thread to run my `NSURLConnection`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of `MBProgressHUD` are you using? At v0.4 (the last on), there is no such method. Instead is `showWhileExecuting`, which says:

```
    /**
 * Shows the HUD while a background task is executing in a new thread, then hides the HUD.
 *
 * This method also takes care of NSAutoreleasePools so your method does not have to be concerned with setting up a
 * pool.
 *
 * @param method The method to be executed while the HUD is shown. This method will be executed in a new thread.
 * @param target The object that the target method belongs to.
 * @param object An optional object to be passed to the method.
 * @param animated If set to YES the HUD will disappear using the current animationType. If set to NO the HUD will not use
 * animations while disappearing.
 */
- (void)showWhileExecuting:(SEL)method 
                  onTarget:(id)target 
                withObject:(id)object 
                  animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

What you should do is show just the **HUD** and remove it when delegates are fired. You should run the connection, not the Improves formatting.. Everything will be OK as long as you use asynchronous connections.

Something like [this](http://snipplr.com/view/26643/mbprogresshud-with-an-asynchronous-nsurlconnection-call/).

Comment: In addition the latest MBProgressHUD demo app also contains a NSURLConnection sample: https://github.com/matej/MBProgressHUD/blob/master/Demo/Classes/HudDemoViewController.m#L208